# Adding to 'required' in referenced JSON schema

Tags: python, json

I am having a go at building a nested JSON schema and I am trying to make as many components as reusable as possible. So I have something like the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "title": "low_level_obj",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "properties": {
    "prop1":{"type": "string"},
    "prop2":{"type": "string"},
    "prop3":{"type": "string"}
  },
  "required": ["prop1"]
}
```

This schema is stored as low_level_obj_schema.json and referenced by a number of other schema, such as the one below:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "title": "higher_level",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "our_obj": {
      "$ref":"file:low_level_obj_schema.json"
    },
    "some_string": {"type": "string"}
  },
  "required": [
    "our_obj",
    "some_string"
  ]
}
```

I would like to be able to change the requirements for the low_level_obj from the higher_level schema - i.e. For this particular instance of the low_level_object I want to be sure that Prop2 also exists.

I tried the following in the higher_level schema:

```
"our_obj": {
   "$ref":"file:low_level_obj_schema.json"
   "required": ["prop2"]
},
```

When I run this through pythons jsonschema.validate I don't receive an error but the validation passes whether "prop2" is in my object instance or not. So I assume the requirement is being overwritten or ignored. I have tried removing the "required" constraint from the low_level_object but that didn't help.

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation but I suspect I am being a bit of a dill. Is there any way to do this - surely I won't need a whole new schema?

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be to use one of the oneOf, allOf, anyOf keywords. I used the following snippet in the higher level schema:

```
"our_obj": {
   "oneOf": [{"$ref":"file:low_level_obj_schema.json"}],
   "required": ["prop2"]
},
```

Now, validating against the following data:

```
test_data_1 = {our_obj: {"prop1": "text", "prop2": "text"}, "some_string": "text"}
test_data_2 = {our_obj: {"prop1": "text", "prop3": "text"}, "some_string": "text"}
test_data_3 = {our_obj: {"prop1": "text"}, "some_string": "text"}
test_data_4 = {our_obj: {"prop2": "text"}, "some_string": "text"}
```

gives the following responses:

```
test_data 1: Valid 
test_data 2: Data Validation Failed: u'prop2' is a required property 
test_data 3: Data Validation Failed: u'prop2' is a required property 
test_data 4: Data Validation Failed: {"prop2": "text"} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

This is my desired behaviour but I can't help but feel that there should be another way.